# Finding a line integral of $5ydx+7xdy$.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Evaluate the line integral $$\int_C5ydx+7xdy $$ where $C$ is the straight line path from $(2,3)$ to $(7, 5)$.

I don't know the way to do that I tried many ways but I still could not get the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating line integrals is just a combination of two kinds of problem which I expect you have studied already: (1) parametrise the path; (2) substitute into the integral.  You should make sure you know how to parametrise familiar paths like straight lines and circles.  In this case the line is given by
$$x=2+5t\ ,\quad y=3+2t$$
for $t$ from $0$ to $1$.  Hence
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=5\ ,\quad \frac{dy}{dt}=2$$
and substituting into the integral gives
$$I=\int_C \Bigl(5y\frac{dx}{dt}+7x\frac{dy}{dt}\Bigr)dt
   =\int_0^1 (5(3+2t)(5)+7(2+5t)(2))\,dt\ .$$
I'm sure you can take it from here.